# C / determine port on which a packet was received

Tags: c, sockets

I have created four sockets with different port configurations. With the `select` function I read from one of the four file descriptors. But how can I find out on which port I received the UDP packet, I do only have the file descriptor, right? Depending on the port I need to process received packets differently. The `recv_from` function fills a `struct sockaddr` from which I can read out the source port of the packet, but not the destination port.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `select` you add all four sockets to the set you want to check, and when `select` returns the set will contain the active sockets.

You now have two ways of figuring out which specific socket/port you get back from `select`:

1. Compare to the sockets you have.
2. Get the local port (though `getsockname`) and compare to the ports.

I recommend the first alternative.